# Replace one character with another and vice versa in a string

Tags: string, bash, sed, replace, tr

I want to replace all slashes '/' with backslashes '\' and vice versa.

My naive solution is to do this with `tr` but then I need a placeholder character, which I don't think is very pretty:

```
tr '/' '¢' | tr '\\' '/' | tr '¢' '\\'
```

and this also only works as long as there never appears a '¢' in my input, which in my case most probably is enough - but hey, who knows? Of course it is easy to take this same idea and make it more robust by using `sed` and then replace '¢' with some arbitrarily random string - like '½|#&¬_$' or something.

But I wanted to know if there is some single bash command to achieve this, which would make this thing shorter, more readable and more robust. Maybe `sed` can do this out of the box?

---

While we are at it, what is the correct name for this operation? Like 'bidirectional replace'. If I knew that my google-searches would probably have been more fruitful. I also tried 'swap characters' but I only found regular replacing stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need an intermediate character for this since `tr` traverses the string only once and hence a character will never get replaced more than once.  The following `tr` command should do it:

```
tr '/\' '\\/' <<< '//\\ then \\// and / and finally a \ in the string'
```

yields

```
\\// then //\\ and \ and finally a / in the string
```

Or, more simply:

```
tr ab ba <<< "ab ba bb aa" # yields "ba ab aa bb"
```

You can also use `sed`:

```
sed 'y#/\\#\\/#' <<< '//\\ then \\// and / and finally a \ in the string'
```

yields

```
\\// then //\\ and \ and finally a / in the string
```

From `man sed`:

> [2addr]y/string1/string2/
>
> Replace all occurrences of characters in string1 in the pattern space with the corresponding characters from string2.
>     Any character other than a backslash or newline can be used instead of a slash to delimit the strings.
>     Within string1 and string2, a backslash followed by an ``n'' is replaced by a newline character.
>     A pair of backslashes is replaced by a literal backslash. Finally, a backslash followed by any other character (except a newline) is that literal character.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you can add in there that the more general thing (which I learned from this) is: with `tr` replacement happens element-wise. In `tr ab xy` 'a' gets replaced by 'x' and 'b' gets replaced by 'y', and hence `tr ab ba` will replace 'a' with 'b' and vice versa. That was the more general thing I was missing about `tr`. The example with backslashes is a bit unfortunate, because of the escaping, which really wasn't my point and kind of clutters the question (and thereby the answers).

Comment: If you edit your answer and add the above mentioned things, I'll be happy to accept it (tomorrow) - it also would then better fit the title. Btw. I like the edit

Answer (score 1):

```
tr \\\\/ /\\\\
```

Input:

```
//fgdf\\
```

Output:

```
\\fgdf//
```

Why 4 backslashes?  Two backslashes make one backslash in shell, so `tr` receives `\\/` and `/\\`.  It has its own backslash sequences, so it interprets two backslashes as a backshash.

Comment: The correct answer to your question of `Why 4 backslashes?` is `Because I didn't quote my strings appropriately`. Always quote scripts/strings using single quotes unless you NEED double quotes to perform a specific task (e.g. variable expansion) and then always use double quotes unless you NEED no quotes to perform a specific task (e.g. wildcard expansion).

Comment: Quotes are not better than no quotes, do not make the expression simpler, and do not add anything.

Comment: Mr Morton just picks up on me, trying to add negative comment in any my answer.  This guy is very active in my answers, probably having something against me.

Comment: As far as I'm aware I have never heard of you, you're just one more anonymous `user<numbers>` account among hundreds of such accounts, and if I've left comments under any of your questions or answers then they're entirely about that question or answer. Your statement that `Quotes are not better than no quotes, do not make the expression simpler, and do not add anything.` is completely wrong (demonstrably so in this answer alone!) and you can google "quoting variables" or read any introductory shell programming tutorial if you'd like to learn more about the issue.